# Why did I failed to connect to websocket?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, websocket

The code of Node server with `ws` module:

```
show = console.log

WS = require('ws').Server
wss = new WS port: 8080
wss.on 'connection', (ws) ->
  show 'a connection'
  ws.on 'message', (message) ->
    show 'received: %s', message
  ws.send 'something'
```

I can connect to websocket by running the code below on the same server,
and it gives out `"a connection"`:

```
WS = require 'ws'
ws = new WS 'ws://localhost:8080'
```

But when I run these lines of code from browser, there's no respose:

```
s = new WebSocket('ws://184.82.253.196:8080');
s.send('nothing');
```

What's problem, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websocket server start listening only `127.0.0.1` by default. Use this code to start listen all interfaces.

```
show = console.log

WS = require('ws').Server
wss = new WS port: 8080, host: '0.0.0.0'
wss.on 'connection', (ws) ->
  show 'a connection'
  ws.on 'message', (message) ->
    show 'received: %s', message
  ws.send 'something'
```