# JavaScript Websocket only works on localhost

Tags: javascript, websocket

Can anyone tell me how to use JavaScript to create a wss connection with a remote IP address?

My websocket only works on `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`

```
ws = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:13529");
ws.onopen = function() {
  alert("连接成功");
  ws.send('tom');
  alert("给服务端发送一个字符串：tom");};
  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
  alert("收到服务端的消息：" + e.data);
};
```

After I change 127.0.0.1 to my IP address, the connection cannot be established.

I found a post [Why did I failed to connect to websocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083966/why-did-i-failed-to-connect-to-websocket/12084151#12084151).

It says setting '0.0.0.0' can solve this problem. However, I changed my codes as following, it cannot run.

[image]

The error message is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I also install a ssl cert:
[install ssl cert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRJor.png)

Comment: Are you sure the server is setup for secure web sockets ? You'd need an ssl certificate for that.

Comment: Yes. I am sure. The server can be connected by localhost. I have installed a ssl certificate for it, but the connection still failed. I think adding 0.0.0.0 might be helpful, but I don't kown how to do it.

Comment: I'll need more information to say anything further.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me which information you need?

Comment: Server code, specifically SSL configuration part. Any reverse proxy configuration.

Comment: I am sorry the server code is not in my hand. The server is a exe file provide by the third party. Still thanks.

Comment: OK. How do you secure it with SSL then ?

Comment: I just install a ssl certificate also provided by the same third party.

Comment: What do you mean by install ?

Comment: I download a certificate , open it. click "install certificate " and continue. I update a snapshot for the certificate. You can see it in my question.

Comment: That's not an SSL certificate. I am guessing the software is supposed to run on local device only and that certificate is for that.
I should have added this earlier, I don't know of any CA that provides SSL for IP address. Why don't you ask the 3rd party to provide you information on how to run that software on a remote server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked their document. All demos them provided are running in local. I will try to communicate with them to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets do not look like they are going to get standardized with raw socket support.

**Or more specifically the raw socket portions which are needed to directly communicate between two browsers without the need of a host server to reform the data.**

But to answer your question, within the google web apps ([to be discontinued](http://www.omgchrome.com/not-joke-google-killing-chrome-apps/) early 2018 per chrome press release) They do have a web server running with websockets using [this code / web app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) *(Web Server for Chrome
offered by chromebeat.com)* which allows other systems to access the web server. I've not examined their code.

Given the bad news I would suggest using nodejs.

https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/ current published.

> Following HTTP procedures here could introduce serious security
>   problems in a Web browser context. For example, consider a host with a
>   WebSocket server at one path and an open HTTP redirector at another.
>   Suddenly, any script that can be given a particular WebSocket URL can
>   be tricked into communicating to (and potentially sharing secrets
>   with) any host on the Internet, even if the script checks that the URL
>   has the right hostname.

https://w3c.github.io/websockets/ development

> No one in the Web Platform Working Group is actively working on this
>   specification. For the latest version of The WebSocket API use the
>   WHATWG Living Standard.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network

> To enable Web applications to maintain bidirectional communications
>   with server-side processes, this specification introduces the
>   WebSocket interface.
>
> This interface **does not allow for raw access to the underlying
>   network.** For example, this interface could not be used to implement an
>   IRC client without proxying messages through a custom server.

The web server requires raw access to sockets :(

Comment: Wayne - I'm not sure I understand your statement "Websockets do not look like they are going to get standardized as they stand today"... there's already a proposed standard (vs. a proposed draft) for the protocol itself (RFC 6455). The RFC is widely implemented. The client side API isn't standardized, but it's uniform as a "Living Standard"... Are you saying these will all be "dropped" and support for Websockets will disappear?

Comment: The raw socket portions .... var socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.listen(8080); ... that you need are not implemented outside of web apps ... https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network ... and developer installations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/TPC_Socket_API ... what is implemented is incomplete, because of security concerns.

Comment: @Myst and I really hope they change their mind, I like the possibilities of raw sockets to be able to setup a browser to share information to other browsers. And, I like web apps to be able to create lite weight applications in. I'm very sad they are not going forward with these.

Comment: I think the question was specifically about Websockets and not about TCP/IP sockets. OP also posts code (in image) relating to a node.js websocket server.

Comment: I agree that raw TCP/IP sounds cool, but the Websocket overhead isn't as big as you might think - except for the message masking part, the message wrapping is very straight forward and flexible. Games obviously suffer from lack of UDP support, but the current HTTP upgrade request (that starts the connection) helps with firewalls and proxies that require the HTTP(S) ports.

Comment: @Myst if you want to read the messages directly you need the raw socket portions, otherwise you are just sending json messages and may need a server to finish the delivery. AJAX already does that :(. I'm sad about it.

Comment: I have some good news for you - Websockets use both text and binary messages. You don't have to use JSON, you can send streams of binary data if you wish (or streams of text data). Many frameworks use JSON messages (i.e. socket.io) to allow for added features and ease of use, but the Websocket protocol itself is pretty much a light message wrapper protocol.

Comment: P.S. Could you update the answer so it doesn't say "Websockets" When you're writing about raw TCP/IP sockets...? I don't want to down-vote.

Comment: @myst If I could send a message from my laptop to my cell phone without using a server I would be happy. Even text, which can be xbase64ed. Right now what can be sent from the browse can not be read with another browser directly, expect within development which Mozilla and Chrome are saying they are not going to development them out to production as they stand.

Comment: @Wayne Honestly, I am new to js and webscoket. Just to confirm, I need to use node.js. Is it right? In fact, I work on a java project, which needs to connect with a third party sever. As demo provided by third party, the code is raw socket by javascript. Meanwhile, all demo them provide are locally. In this case, I might communicate with the third party how to connect the server remotely. Thanks again for you help. Thanks @ Myst too.

Comment: @molly, you don't have to, but nodejs will give you the API to do socket connections and it will continue to support the API. Hence in 6 months, 12 months, etc your application will continue to work and be supported within an off the shelf distributed product.

Comment: @molly "the code is raw socket by javascript" does not ring any bells with me. stephenwvickers/node-raw-socket github, https://github.com/stephenwvickers/node-raw-socket may help as a starting point?

Comment: @molly as I said in my answer, Web Server for Chrome offered by chromebeat.com is using Chrome Apps raw socket API. being a web app it is possible to locate and look at the source code, doing so may reveal what needs to be changed ... extensions, developer mode, Inspect views: background page ... but Chrome is going to be ending web apps in early 2018, and raw sockets only exists as a web app api. For me web apps are the fastest way to create something, I hope they change their minds.